# compass config issues on compilation / watch

Tags: sass, config, watch, compiled, compass-sass

I have this:

```
Project
├───public_html/
│   ├───css/
│   |    └───style.css
│   |
│   ├───img/
│   |
│   ├───js/
│   |
│   └───index.html
|
├───scss/
│   ├───ie.scss
│   ├───print.scss
|   └───style.scss
|
└───config.rb
```

config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir   = "public_html/css"
sass_dir  = "scss"
output_style = :compressed
```

and I'm doing:

```
compass watch "scss/style.css"
```

Its creating (overriding) the style.css as expected. (so far so good).
But when I edit the style.scss and save it its compiling inside the scss folder with this:

```
...
├───scss/
|   ├───.sass-cache/
|   ├───ie.css
|   ├───ie.scss
|   ├───print.css
|   ├───print.scss
│   ├───screen.css
│   ├───screen.scss
│   └───config.rb
...
```

like ignoring the first config.rb and moving the root inside the scss folder.

In addition I just want screen.scss compiled, the rest will be included.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I've ended up **compiling the files directly from the scss forlder** and I now have there the main config.rb
I still would like to have control about where the config.rb is and the subfolders that are getting filled in the compilation process.

If anyone has a way to better control this, please let me know.

The other thing: "to compile just a few of the scss files"

The way to do this is to **rename the files you don't want to be compiled** starting with **underscore** 
**_print.scss** (instead of print.scss). The good thing is that you can still **import the files as you normally would, without the underscore** (even if the actual file has the starting underscore)

```
@import "print.scss"
```